# Should we model $Y$ or change from baseline?

Tags: regression, modeling

$Y$ is measured at baseline and then after 1 and 2 hours ($Y_0$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$).

I want to fit a model against baseline and treatment arm in order to compare the two treatment arms in terms of change from baseline.

Does it make a difference to use $Y_j$ or $Y_j - Y_0$ as response ($j = 1, 2$)? Or both models are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most commonly used approach in randomized controlled trials is to use a model (such as e.g. analysis of covariance) with $y_0$ as a covariate in the model. This is generally regarded as a good practice. In that case, it does not matter, at all, as far as the estimated treatment difference is concerned, whether you look at $y_j-y_0$ or $y_j$. If one does not use $y_0$ as a covariate, then it does make a difference.

A number of authors have discussed this, e.g. Senn in his book "Statistical Issues in Drug Development", in this article

> Senn, S. (2006). Change from baseline and analysis of covariance
>   revisited. Statistics in medicine, 25(24), 4334-4344.

and probably a lot of other authors, too.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine you do an experiment where you prepare some object with a substance, measure the amount of the substance $Y_{0}$ and then apply the treatment (or do nothing) and then measure the amount of the substance $Y_{1}$ and later $Y_{2}$. So you are investigating growth or something comparable.

Here is an example where using $Y_1$ or $Y_{2}$ instead of $Y_{1} - Y_{0}$ or $Y_{2} - Y_{0}$ could go wrong:
Imagine you accidentally applied too much of the substance in the treatment arm samples. If you then only fit $Y_{1}$ or $Y_{2}$, then you might be fitting just that difference in the amount of applied substance instead of the actual growth. You avoid sources of error by fitting $Y_{1} - Y_{0}$ or $Y_{2} - Y_{0}$. (However, this example is a bit flawed: your growth could also depend on the amount of the substance present at $Y_{0}$, then your results are still affected by the different amounts of substance at $Y_{0}$. In that case you would need to control for $Y_{0}$ in the model.)

Also, you state your research question as

> ... to compare the two treatment arms in terms of change from baseline.

So, you are actually only interested in the change from baseline after applying a treatment or doing nothing.

I would say it is always better to measure your target directly instead of measuring a proxy.

Comment: Comments on the -1 are welcome.